# Inject HTML metadata into a URL loaded in Cypress

Tags: javascript, html, cypress, meta-tags

I want to write Cypress tests for a website that is being loaded as an iFrame in a parent environment. The parent environment injects metatags when loading the site, and I need to replicate this functionality in Cypress.

Do to so, I need to fetch the contents of a URL passed by a test runner, modify the `<head></head>` of the HTML to add meta tags like this:

```
metaTag.setAttribute("dark-mode", "true");
```

then load the site with the metadata. However, if I fetch the contents, add metadata, but then run `cy.visit(URL)`, only the unmodified site is loaded.

I know Cypress allows accessing metatags, but does it support injecting them?

Answer (score 3):

You could add headers in the `onLoad` event of `cy.visit()`.

```js
cy.visit('https://example.com', {
  onLoad: (win) => {
    const head = win.document.querySelector('head')
    const meta = win.document.createElement('meta')
    meta.setAttribute("dark-mode", "true")
    head.appendChild(meta)
  }
})

cy.get('head meta[dark-mode]')
  .should(
    'have.attr',
    'dark-mode',
    'true',
  )
```

[image]

Comment: So this works in theory - I had to modify it like so to get the tag set correctly:

```
      const darkModeTag = win.document.createElement("meta");
      darkModeTag.setAttribute("name", "dark-mode");
      darkModeTag.setAttribute("content", "true");
```
However, the page is being loaded before the tags are set, so the actual affects of the tags are not being applied.

Comment: Indeed, there wasn't much to go on in your question so I made a best guess as to which event to use. However, this is the **pattern** you need to use when loading headers on a page visit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TesterDick's suggestion, I was able to get the following to work:

```js
  cy.visit("myurl.com", {
    onBeforeLoad: win => {
      const head = win.document.querySelector("head") as HTMLHeadElement;
      const darkModeTag = win.document.createElement("meta");
      darkModeTag.setAttribute("name", "dark-mode");
      darkModeTag.setAttribute("content", "true");
      const featureTag = win.document.createElement("meta");
      head.appendChild(darkModeTag);
    },
```

This results in the page loading with the correct metadata set.